# Magento redirect loop after Base URL and htaccess change

Tags: magento, base-url, redirect-loop

I'm on pretty fresh Magento 1.9 installation.

I was trying to force users of my website to surf via www.example.com instead of example.com so i followed instructions here:
http://kb.siteground.com/how_to_redirect_magento_to_open_through_www/

Basically I added the 2 lines to my .htaccess file at my public_html, after the default "RewriteEngine on":

```
##enable rewrites

    #Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on

############################################
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I then went to my Magento backend at 
system > config > web > unsecure > base url

And changed it from http://example.com to http://www.example.com

After those 2 things i did, I'm getting an error "This web page has a redirect loop".
Also notice that 
- when i key into my URL bar www.example.com, it gets replaced with example.com with the redirect loop error.
- when i key into my URL bar example.com, it gets replaced with www.example.com with the redirect loop error.

Any idea anyone?

Answer (score 1):

I seem to have fixed this.

I realized my changes at:
system > config > web > unsecure > base url

Were not actually being saved properly.
I commented out the lines from the .htaccess file, and i attempted to update 
system > config > web > unsecure > base url
again ,and finally it saved successfuly.

Seemed the .htaccess entries were playing games with my system backend settings.

Now my site seems to work fine.
Effectively all i did was make the change from http://example.com to http://www.example.com at
system > config > web > unsecure > base url

No effective changes to .htaccess

Answer (score 0):

Clear cache from var directory by deleting all files in cache folder and page-cache folder for Magento 2.0